# Migrating web application to Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am exploring the possibility of moving a java web application to Azure app service. The application when on-prem reads from a property file while starting up.

Is there a possibility to pass or place the property file to app service ? If not - what is the suggestion to move such legacy application to Azure app service ?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider having them in the [**`AppSettings`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#application-settings). If it's dot net app you can use **`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]`** will return value from the portal

Also the 2nd question, it depends on various facors you can make decision according to the diagram below,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/images/compute-decision-tree.svg